# Correct way of defining a model in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

What is the correct way of defining a model in Ionic 3 with getters and setters?

I followed this.

```
export class ItemModel{
    private _name: string;

    constructor(private n: string){
      this._name = n;
    }

    get name(): string
    {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(name: string)
    {
        this._name = name;
    }
}
```

Is it correct?

In some forums it was mentioned about a need to keep the code very short. So does that mean using getters and setters would affect the performance somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript [supports accessors natively](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors), which effectively handle the job of getters and setters. You don't need to manually define them as separate methods.

Answer (score 3):

With `typescript`, you can just define it like below.You don't need to do big work.`Typescript` will do the rest.

> TypeScript supports getters/setters as a way of intercepting accesses
>   to a member of an object. This gives you a way of having finer-grained
>   control over how a member is accessed on each object.

```
export class ItemModel {
    name: string;
    note: string;
}

let itemModel = new ItemModel();
itemModel.name= "My Name";
```

Comment: Interface is best way to declare model