# What is the error in this code ? I had add a new class and imported into .ts file , then defined an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The console shows error and says Recipe wasn't defined.

I have added the class definition which is separate file in the end.

The import statement :

```
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';
```

The new Recipe

```
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
    recipes : Recipe[] = [
        new Recipe('Test 1','Test Description','https://www.gimmesomeoven.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Cajun-Jambalaya-Recipe-with-Andouille-Sausage-Shrimp-and-Chicken-3-1.jpg') 
];

    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit() {

    }
    }
```

The class definition:

```
export class Recipe {
    public name : string;
    public description : string;
    public imagePath : string;

    constructor(name :string, description : string, imagePath : string){
        this.name=name;
        this.description=description;
        this.imagePath=imagePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: A better place to ask this question is the course forum ;) Look through the module and app files to see if you have Recipe defined in all the places where it is required.

Answer (score 0):

possibly your declaration:

```
import { Recipe } from '../recipe.model';

 export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {
    public recipes: Recipe;
 constructor(){
   this.recipes = new Recipe('Test 1','Test 
   Description','https://www.gimmesomeoven.com/wp-
   content/uploads/2014/03/Cajun-Jambalaya-Recipe-with-Andouille-Sausage-
  Shrimp-and-Chicken-3-1.jpg');
 }

 ngOnInit() {

  }
 }
```

Comment: The console still shows the same error. Recipe is not defined.

Comment: this approach? perhaps assign  the attributes one at a time.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215565/correct-way-of-defining-a-model-in-ionic-3